# C# 7 Out variable and pattern variable declarations are not allowed within a query clause

Tags: c#, out, c#-7.0

Why out variables are not allowed in query clause?

If I use out variables here it fails:

```
string json = "{'PayDays':['2017-07-07','2017-07-21','2017-08-04','2017-08-18']}";
var pd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accounting>(json);

var rm = from item in pd.PayDays
     where (DateTime.TryParse(item, out DateTime dateresult)) ?
    dateresult.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days >= 0 ? true : false : false      
    select item;
rm.Dump();
```

But old way works:

```
DateTime result;
var rm = from item in pd.PayDays
         where DateTime.TryParse(item, out result) ? (result.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days >= 0 ? true : false) : false
         select item;
rm.Dump();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the [relevant LDM notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2016/LDM-2016-12-07-14.md#expression-variables-in-query-expressions).

The conclusion:

> We won't have time to do this feature in C# 7.0. If we want to leave ourselves room to do it in the future, we need to make sure that we don't allow expression variables in query clauses to mean something else today, that would contradict such a future.
>
> The current semantics is that expression variables in query clauses
>   are scoped to only the query clause. That means two subsequent query
>   clauses can use the same name in expression variables, for instance.
>   That is inconsistent with a future that allows those variables to
>   share a scope across query clause boundaries.
>
> Thus, if we want to allow this in the future we have to put in some
>   restrictions in C# 7.0 to protect the design space. We have a couple
>   of options:
>
> - Disallow expression variables altogether in query clauses
> - Require that
>     all expression variables in a given query expression have different
>     names
>
> The former is a big hammer, but the latter requires a lot of
>   work to get right - and seems at risk for not blocking off everything
>   well enough.

and

> We will neither do expression variables nor deconstruction in C# 7.0, but would like to do them in the future. In order to protect our ability to do this, we will completely disallow expression variables inside query clauses, even though this is quite a big hammer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the translation you showed works fine for normal LINQ to objects, but would be problematic for other providers, like PLINQ or Entity Framework.

For example, consider the translation you proposed for your query modified to use PLINQ:

```
DateTime result;
var rm = from item in pd.PayDays.AsParallel()
         where DateTime.TryParse(item, out result) ? (result.Subtract(DateTime.Now).Days >= 0 ? true : false) : false
         select item;
var list = rm.ToList();
```

This code is not thread-safe, because multiple threads share a single `result` variable and you're likely going to get incorrect results, because they will try to use it at the same time.

There are ways to correctly translate such queries, at least in some cases, but they're not trivial, so `out` variables are simply not allowed in LINQ query syntax. Though [there is a proposal to allow them in a future version of C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/159).

Comment: From the language perspective, the translation seems fairly straightforward: the equivalent of `from item in pd.PayDays.AsParallel() let resultHolder = new DisplayClass() where DateTime.TryParse(item, out resultHolder.result) ? ... : ... select item;`, with the same type of generated `DisplayClass` classes that already get generated for other reasons. Can you give an example where this simple approach wouldn't work or would behave in unexpected ways?